# Conditional formatting in R referencing data in other rows

Tags: r

Below is a dataframe (`df`) in which I need to replace information based on a set of conditions. See `result` for desired solution. However, one of my conditions needs to reference a value in a previous row and I cannot figure out why the code is not working. My current code replaces values in row 12, but given the last condition statement this should not be happening. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

I prefer solutions in base package, but please include other solutions as they could be useful to others.

Thanks in advance for your time.

```
# rm(list=ls())

df <- read.table(text = "PROBLEM SITE LENGTH
x   S9.2    249
fix y   1
x   S9.2    5
x   S9.2    5
x   S9.2    5
x   S9.2    5
x   S9.2    5
fix y   2
fix y   2
x   S3.2    2
x   S3.2    2
fix y   1
x   S3.2    22
", header = TRUE)

result <- read.table(text = "PROBLEM SITE LENGTH
x   S9.2    249
fix S9.2    1
x   S9.2    5
x   S9.2    5
x   S9.2    5
x   S9.2    5
x   S9.2    5
fix y   2
fix y   2
x   S3.2    2
x   S3.2    2
fix y   1
x   S3.2    22
", header = TRUE)

# Partially working code. Note the last condition statement appears to be the problem.
df$SITE[df$PROBLEM == "fix" & df$LENGTH == 1 & c(df$LENGTH[- 1], 0 ) >= 5] = 
  df$SITE[which(df$PROBLEM == "fix" & df$LENGTH == 1 & c(df$LENGTH[- 1], 0 ) >= 5) - 1]
```

Comment: Can you please explain in words what your conditions are instead of we trying to figure out from your code?

Comment: Please do not post code that will erase the entire workspace of anyone who copies and pastes it without realizing that it is there.  I have commented the offending line out.

Comment: @Ronak Shah. I need the code to replace data in the `SITE` column based on three conditions. Two of the three conditions are related to data in the same row as the `SITE`: i) is the values in the `PROBLEM == fix` and ii) is the `LENGTH == 1`. The tricky part of the code for me is the third condition, because it needs to reference  the value in the previous row of the `LENGTH` column...which is where my code falls apart. So..for line 2, the code needs to see what the `LENGTH` is in lines 2 and 1. I can try to further clarify if needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
df$SITE2 <- with(df,
  ifelse(PROBLEM == "fix" & LENGTH == 1 & c(FALSE, LENGTH[-nrow(df)] > 5),
         c(NA, SITE[-nrow(df)]), SITE)
)
df
#    PROBLEM SITE LENGTH SITE2
# 1        x S9.2    249  S9.2
# 2      fix    y      1  S9.2
# 3        x S9.2      5  S9.2
# 4        x S9.2      5  S9.2
# 5        x S9.2      5  S9.2
# 6        x S9.2      5  S9.2
# 7        x S9.2      5  S9.2
# 8      fix    y      2     y
# 9      fix    y      2     y
# 10       x S3.2      2  S3.2
# 11       x S3.2      2  S3.2
# 12     fix    y      1     y
# 13       x S3.2     22  S3.2
```

The issue is that you were trying to reference the previous `LENGTH` with `[-1]`, which has the vector-logical effect of looking at the *next* value. When we're looking at row 2 (with "fix" and "1"), we want to compare against the 249, which we then need in the second position of some vector.

```r
cbind(df[,1:3], `LENGTH[-1]` = c(df$LENGTH[-1], 0), `LENGTH[-nrow(df)]` = c(0, df$LENGTH[-nrow(df)]))
#    PROBLEM SITE LENGTH LENGTH[-1] LENGTH[-nrow(df)]
# 1        x S9.2    249          1                 0
# 2      fix    y      1          5               249
# 3        x S9.2      5          5                 1
# 4        x S9.2      5          5                 5
# 5        x S9.2      5          5                 5
# 6        x S9.2      5          5                 5
# 7        x S9.2      5          2                 5
# 8      fix    y      2          2                 5
# 9      fix    y      2          2                 2
# 10       x S3.2      2          2                 2
# 11       x S3.2      2          1                 2
# 12     fix    y      1         22                 2
# 13       x S3.2     22          0                 1
```

Comment: Thanks @r2evans! Your example clearly illustrates the problems with my original code.